# Использование курсоров MsSql

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Помогите написать запрос, пожалуйста. Никак не выходит, постоянно разные ошибки. Прочитав документацию, я поняла, что тут похоже надо курсоры использовать. Используется БД AdventureWorks2012

Задание:
Вы решаете написать SQL-скрипт для создания строки SQL-запроса, который возвращал бы те строки из таблицы, которые содержат искомое значение в любом текстовом столбце. Напишите SQL-скрипт для поиска произвольного значения(подстроки –значение для поиска необходимо задавать через переменную) в текстовом столбце (строки) произвольной таблице (результирующий запрос должен возвращать все столбцы из таблицы).
Вам необходимо вывести текст сформированного SQL-запроса на экран с помощью оператора PRINT.
Для демонстрации работоспособности получившегося сценария выполните поиск значения «Bike» в таблице SalesLT.Product.

Строки ищу так:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'Product';

DECLARE @Schema nvarchar(50);
SET @Schema = (Select DISTINCT Table_Schema From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME = @TableName);

select COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName, DATA_TYPE AS Type
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext') AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema;
```

Comment: Курсор тут не нужен. Надо запросить в системных таблицах список строковых полей таблицы и агрегировать их в текст запроса, который потом выполнить динамически.

Comment: По условию задачи нужно именно с курсорами. Так-то я написала. Думаю, удобно будет создать хранимую процедуру, вот только как реализовать... не получается

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(128) = 'SMS_StreamTelecom'
DECLARE @Schema nvarchar(128) = (SELECT TOP 1 Table_Schema FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName)
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM "' + @Schema + '"."' + @TableName + '" WHERE 1 <> 1' + CHAR(13)
DECLARE @SubsrtingForSearch nvarchar(MAX) = 'REST SendSms'
    
SELECT @Query += 'OR "' + COLUMN_NAME + '" LIKE ''%' + @SubsrtingForSearch + '%''' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
    AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext')
    
PRINT @Query
--EXEC(@Query) --Если нужно выполнить запрос, то раскомментируй эту строку
```